# Look, he’s reading a/the book about animals

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

It is known that if we speak about an object for the first time, we use "a" article, but in this case which article is idiomatic? I think "the" article is more appropriate here because they indicated on the particular book. Am I right?

> It’s so good that the child likes to read! Look, he’s reading **a/the** book about animals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular book is *not* indicated here, unless we already knew that there was only one book about animals.

If we have never seen the child or the book before, then we would definitely say "**a** book about animals", because it is one of many possible books about animals.

If we had said before, "This child has a book about trucks, a book about animals, and a book about airplanes," THEN we would say, "Look, he's reading **the** book about animals" because we know there is only one book about animals that we could be referring to, the one that we have already mentioned.

Comment: Indeed. _The_ implies that the speaker expects the hearer to know which book is being referred to.

Comment: @stangdon, Thank you for good explanation! I suppose, also they can use "the book" if they gifted particularly this book before even if this child have many books about animals. Am I right?

Comment: @Sergei  You're very welcome!  Yes, "the book" would also make sense if we knew in advance that it was referring to one specific book about animals.

Comment: [There are five books on the table. One is about animals] "Look, he's reading **the book** about animals.

Answer (score 3):

"It is known that if we speak about an object for the first time, we use "a" article"

I don't know that!  Using "the" indicates definiteness. It means the identity of object that the noun is referred to is definitely known.

One way to create definiteness is to have mentioned something before, but that is not the only way. Shared knowledge can also create definiteness. In your case, if the speaker and listener have some shared knowledge "there is only one book about animals and we both know that that book" then  "the book about animals" is correct, and it doesn't need to have been mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

An easy test is that "a" means "*one X (among many)*".

In your context, it makes perfect sense to say, "*Look, he’s reading **one book about animals (among many)**.*" This makes sense because there are many books about animals in the world, and he's reading one of them.

The first time you refer to a particular thing, unless it's unique it is "one thing (among many)", and referring to it with "a" singles it out from among the many others for focus. After that point, that item *is unique* because it's the one that we are now focused on. Before using "a", we were not focused on it, so "a" was correct.